# I am stuck with a JavaScript algorithm attempting to find the max value of a stack

Tags: javascript, algorithm, stack

I am working on a JavaScript algorithm attempting to go thru the stack and** return -Infinity when the stack is empty** and when **the stack is not empty return the max value inside of this stack**. They require me to use 3 different methods

.pop() which pops the top value of the stack

.push() which pushes a value on to the stack

.peek() which shows me the top value of the stack without modifying the stack

Below is what I  tried which works for all test cases except for when the stack is full of negative values, as well as the code that was provided to me for the class Stack, if I am missing information in any way please let me know and I will update the question to try and make it clearer.

this is **what I tried thus far** it works for all of the test cases except for when the stack is
Stack(-847626, -9234752, -7444), when this happens it returns 0 rather than the greater value of this stack
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdiFA.png)

```
function maxValue(stack) {

  let count = 0;
  while (true) { // while stack is a truthy value
    if (stack.pop() === undefined) {//keep popping from stack until undefined
      return -Infinity

    }
    if(stack.pop()>count){
      count = stack.pop()
    }
    return count
    break
  }



}
```

This is the **class methods for the stack** that where provided to me

```
class Stack {

  constructor(...values) {

    const data = {};

    let index = 0;

    this.push = function (value) {
      if (arguments.length < 1) {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push() requires a value argument');
      }
      if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push(value) received undefined');
      }
      data[index] = value;
      index++;
    };

    this.pop = function () {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      const value = data[last];
      delete data[last];
      index = last;
      return value;
    };

    this.peek = function () {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      return data[last];
    };

    this.print = function () {
      if (index === 0) {
        return 'Stack { <empty> }';
      }
      let output = ' }';
      let last = index - 1;
      for (; last > 0; last--) {
        output = ' <- ' + JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      }
      output = JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      return 'Stack { ' + output;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      this.push(values[i]);
    }

    Object.freeze(this);

  }

}
```

Comment: I am surprised this is passing any test cases. There are quite a few problems. You're popping an element off the stack three times per loop. And you return from the function the first time through the loop. Also, if you ever got to the end of the stack you'd return `-Infinity`.

Comment: would it be possible for you to show me the solution so I could better understand?

Comment: The reason your code can't work for stacks that have all negative numbers is because you set the initial value of `count` to 0. Because no number in the stack is greater than 0, `count` never changes. Change the initial value to `-Infinity`.

Comment: Also, understand that your function alters (empties) the stack. Are you supposed to do that? Or are you expected to put the stack back the way it was before the function returns?

Comment: @JimMischel i am not expected to put the stack back after, thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting that `pop()` removes the top element from the stack. You're calling it three times before actually updating the max value, essentially just throwing two elements in the garbage each iteration.

```js
class Stack {

  constructor(...values) {

    const data = {};

    let index = 0;

    this.push = function (value) {
      if (arguments.length < 1) {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push() requires a value argument');
      }
      if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
        throw new TypeError('stack.push(value) received undefined');
      }
      data[index] = value;
      index++;
    };

    this.pop = function () {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      const value = data[last];
      delete data[last];
      index = last;
      return value;
    };

    this.peek = function () {
      const last = index - 1;
      if (last < 0) return;
      return data[last];
    };

    this.print = function () {
      if (index === 0) {
        return 'Stack { <empty> }';
      }
      let output = ' }';
      let last = index - 1;
      for (; last > 0; last--) {
        output = ' <- ' + JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      }
      output = JSON.stringify(data[last]) + output;
      return 'Stack { ' + output;
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      this.push(values[i]);
    }

    Object.freeze(this);

  }

}

function maxValue(stack) {
  let max = -Infinity;
  while (stack.peek() !== undefined) {
    const next = stack.pop();
    if (next > max) max = next;
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(maxValue(new Stack(-847626, -9234752, -7444)));
```